# How can I access a nested array while using a conditional statement with two operators in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, indexof, conditional-operator

Currently the conditional statement below works like a charm. 
It takes the normal price of the pizza from the item array and changes it from 5.99 to 4.99 when the quantity is 2 and the tags equals pizza. This is fine however I need to add an additional third condition to check and see if the name inside of the item array is equal to "10inch" as it is in the item array at the bottom of the page. How can I achieve this?

```
   if (item.tags == "pizza" && item.quantity === 2){
     item.price = 4.99;
   }
    // This works fine
```

Adding the third condition referencing the name object has proven to be a bit tricky because the name is in a nested array (item.price) I imagine the solution may go something like the following but I'm not sure

```
  if (item.tags == "pizza" && 
      Object.keys(item.price)[0] == "10inch"  && 
      item.quantity === 2){
      // code ....
   }

  // This doesn't work
```

Here is the item array from which the function is working on

```
  "item": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "thumb": "https://foodorderingapp9309.s3-us-west- 
                1.amazonaws.com/CheesySenstions/menu/CheesePizza.JPG",
      "title": "Cheese",
      "body": "If ordering 2 10 inch pizzas or more  discount
               will be applied at checkout",

      "tags": ["pizza"],
      "price": [
          {
              "name": "10inch",
              "value": "5.99",
              "currency": "$"
          },
      }
    ]
```

Comment: `item.tags` is an array, so `item.tags == "pizza"` will not work. You need to use `item.tags.includes("pizza")`

Comment: Where is `quantity` ?

Comment: quantity is coming from a separate function. It's not part of the item array but rather something completely different

Comment: @Barmar the pizza tag is currently working as intended

Comment: That's not possible the way you wrote it. A string will never be equal to an array.

Answer (score 0):

To check the first item in the price array, use `item.price[0].name === '10inch'`

Comment: I suspect what he really wants to do is search the `item.price` array for the one with `name="10inch"` and set/get its price. Not hard-code `[0]`

Comment: @Barmar, Yes i need it take the on that is true`"price": [
        {
          "name": "10inch",
          "value": "5.99",
          "currency": "$"
        },
        {
          "name": "14inch",
          "value": "9.99",
          "currency": "$"
        },
        {
          "name": "16 inch",
          "value": "11.99",
          "currency": "$"
        }
      ]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` method to look for the element of the array with the matching name.

```
if (item.tags.includes("pizza") && item.quantity == 2) {
    let teninch = item.price.find(i => i.name == "10inch");
    if (teninch) {
        teninch.value = "4.99";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what works
Thank you for all your help.

```
 item.price.name ==='10inch'
```

Comment: This can't possibly work. `item.price` is an array, it doesn't have a `name` property.

Comment: @barmar it's a bit more complicated than that i'm afraid

Comment: If this answer works, the object in the question is not accurate.